# How do you set a default policy in Laravel Nova?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-8, policy

Following this, everything works great:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#generating-policies

However, for better security practices, I'd like to have it so that if no policy is set, a Nova resource will default to my ReadOnlyPolicy.php.

Currently, if no policy is set, Nova sets all permissions to true which seems like a bad idea in case a future dev creates a model but forgets to create a policy for it. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I like this approach (and might even implement it in some of my future projects to be honest), but I'm not sure if Laravel supports it. As a workaround though, you could potentially use [`Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#policy-auto-discovery) to provide your own logic to use a default policy with `return false` for all actions (if an existing UserPolicy, PostPolicy, etc doesn't exist).